# Unable to stop Remote Service using Stop-Service

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

```
 Get-Service -ComputerName "SERVERNAME" -Name "SERVICENAME" | Stop-Service -ErrorAction Inquire
```

I am trying to stop a windows service remotely, but it returns an error:

> Stop-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'SERVICENAME.exe'

Even though I specify the correct service name, it seems to add the `exe` part to the name.

When I Run `Get-Service` it works perfectly and gets the Service details, but the moment I add `| Stop-Service` it returns the error above.

```
Get-Service -ComputerName "SERVERNAME" -Name "SERVICENAME"
```

I have also tried `Get-WmiObject` but with no luck.

Everything else seems to work, all commands return the results required except the stop or start service commands where I get this error.

Comment: What is your benefit from caps-locking parts of your text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to pass a -computer name argument to the Stop-Service command. Feels like you may be getting the service from remote computer, then trying to stop the service on local computer.

Try `(Get-Service -computername remotepc -name servicename).Stop()`

Comment: Thank you, that one worked. I initially tried (Get-Service -computername remotepc -name servicename).StopService() but that didnt work. Still fairly new to powershell.